# Same version after patching wpa_supplicant 2.4

Tags: vulnerabilities, wpa2

Why is the version number of wpa_supplicant not increased, when I look with 'man wpa_supplicant' at the bottom it says 16 October 2017 but with 'wpa_supplicant -v' I see v2.4, which is especially vulnerable for KRACK attacks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be fine when the update log op ubuntu / mint says: wpasupplicant:amd64 (2.4-0ubuntu6, 2.4-0ubuntu6.2), this was this morning with mine. (less /var/log/apt/history.log)